# Add number of active products to category navigation menu in magento 2.1.1

Tags: navigation, magento-2.1.1

As the **title** says could anyone help me with adding the number of active **products** within a category to the navigation menu. To clarify i want to make it display as follows:

Product(23)

Other Product(13)

And have it do that for all categories.
Anyone got any idea on how to do this in magento 2.1.1

Answer (score 0):

It is Magento2 default functionality

Go admin side `STORES -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Layered Navigation` : Display Product Count field set `Yes` and save

[image]

**Show frond like**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help but for some reason even though i did exactly what you did it doesnt display the numbers. i tried clearing the cache but that didnt help either

Comment: Pls reindex all via  below command : php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: I ran the command and still the numbers are not shown on the frontend. any other ideas?

Comment: can you share url?

Comment: it is currently running on a localhost. and i made sure the feature was enabled in the admin but cache clearing and reindexing didnt seem to have done anything

Comment: Is there really no more help u can give?